# How to make object of array list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

My project based on *spring boot, Thymeleaf, mysql, html and jQuery.* My Scenario is getting dynamically generated input box data and static input box data need to carried out and to hit the @controller.

I want to POST as a JSON format in a type of **List EntPropertySub** that means **list of class type**, I had a confusion how do I make a list in jQuery. I tried to make a array of object, but it seems error. Please guide me. Here is a sample code

```
var max;
var blockname;
var floors;
var flatstart;
var flatend;
var blockListPropSub[];
for(max=1;max<=x;max++) {
  blockListPropSub[max] = {
    blockname = $('#block'+max).val();
    floors=$('#floor'+max).val();
    flatstart=$('#flats'+max).val();
    flatend=$('#flatsend'+max).val();
  };
}
```

**Here is a complete script**..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $("#addingInp"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $("#addButton"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment now x=1 after x++ x=2,so next code 2%2==0 is true

        $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-top: 20px" class="form-row">'
                +'<div class"form-group col-md-3">'
                +'<label for="block'+x+'">Block</label>'
                +'<input id="block'+x+'" th:field="*{blockListPropSub.blockname}" type="text" name="mytext[]" class="form-control block" placeholder="Enter Name"/>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div class"form-group col-md-4">'
                +'<label for="floor'+x+'">No of floors</label>'
                +'<input id="floor'+x+'" th:field="*{blockListPropSub.floors}" type="text" name="mytext[]" class="form-control floor" placeholder="Start (Ex : 1)"/>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div class"form-group col-md-4">'
                +'<label for="flats'+x+'">No/Name of flats</label>'
                +'<input id="flats'+x+'" th:field="*{blockListPropSub.flatstart}" type="text" name="mytext[]" class="form-control flatstart" placeholder="Start (Ex : A or 1)"/>'
                +'<input id="flatsend'+x+'" th:field="*{blockListPropSub.flatend}" type="text" name="mytext[]" class="form-control flatend" placeholder="End (Ex : Z or 100)"/>'
                +'</div>'

                    +'<a href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1"> X </a>'
                +'</div>'); //add input box
    }
});

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
 //--------------------For Submitting` data to controller
    var url = window.location;
    // SUBMIT FORM
    $("#socityreg").submit(function(event) {
        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();
        ajxPost();
    });

function ajxPost(){

    var max;
    var blockname;
    var floors;
    var flatstart;
    var flatend;
    var blockListPropSub[];
    for(max=1;max<=x;max++)
        {
        blockListPropSub[max]={
            blockname = $('#block'+max).val();
            floors=$('#floor'+max).val();
            flatstart=$('#flats'+max).val();
            flatend=$('#flatsend'+max).val();
                };
        }

    alert(blockListPropSub.blockname[1]);
    // PREPARE FORM DATA
    var formData = {
            property_name : $("#propertyname").val(),
            address1 : $("#inputaddress").val(),
            address2 : $("#inputaddress2").val(),
            city:$("#inputcity").val(),
            state:$("#inputstate").val(),
            country:$("#inputcountry").val(),
            zipcode:$("#inputzip").val(),
            blockListPropSub
    }

    // DO POST
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : url+"/savemasterproperty",
        data :JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {
            if(result == "saved"){
                $("#resultid").html("<strong>" +username+ " Registered Successfully!" );
            }else{
                $("#resultid").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
            }

            alert(result.status);
            console.log(result);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert("Error!");
            alert(url);
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
    // Reset FormData after Posting
        //resetData();


 } 
   /* function resetData(){
        property_name : $("").val(),
        address1 : $("").val(),
address2 : $("").val(),
        city:$("").val(),
        state:$("").val(),
        country:$("").val(),
        zipcode:$("").val(),
    }*/
    });
```

Comment: You will need to replace `=` with `:` inside object literals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to make BlockListPropSub an array, `var blockListPropSub = []`

then use something like `blockname: $('#block' + max).val()` to set the value of `blockname`

```js
var max;
var blockname;
var floors;
var flatstart;
var flatend;
var blockListPropSub = [];
for (max = 1; max <= 2; max++) {
  blockListPropSub.push({
    blockname: max, //$('#block' + max).val();
    floors: max, //$('#floor' + max).val();
    flatstart: max, //$('#flats' + max).val();
    flatend: max, //$('#flatsend' + max).val();
  })
}
console.log(blockListPropSub)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,,but here $('#block' + max).val(); that input box id which value is taken from HTML...please refer the full script that is made here.